# How to get connectionstring in implementing IAuthorization Filter in .Net Core MVC?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core-3.1

I am newbie to .Net Core and I want to call my database to fetch all rights of user from database. So, while implementing IAuthorization Filter I am not able to fetch connectionstring.

**Authorize Attribute:**

```
using Demo.Respositories;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Filters;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using System;

namespace Demo.Web.Providers
{
 [AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class | AttributeTargets.Method)]
public class CustomAuthorizeAttribute : Attribute, IAuthorizationFilter
{
    public void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationFilterContext context)
    {
        try
        {
            if (context.HttpContext.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
            {
                var requiredRights = String.Format("{0}-{1}", context.HttpContext.Request.RouteValues["controller"].ToString(), context.HttpContext.Request.RouteValues["action"].ToString());
                var userName = context.HttpContext.User.Identity.Name;
                if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(userName))
                {
                    
                    var config = context.HttpContext.RequestServices.GetSection<IConfiguration>();
            //Error object does not have defination for GetSection
            string connectionString = config.GetSection("ConnectionStrings:DefaultConnection").Value;
                    
                    var rights = AuthHelper.GetUserRightsByUserName(userName, connectionString);

                    if (!rights.Contains(requiredRights.ToLower()))
                    {
                        context.Result = new RedirectResult("~/account/unauthorized");
                    }
                }
            }
            else
            {
                context.Result = new RedirectResult("~/account/login");
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex) { 
        
        }
    }
}
```

}

**Controller :**

```
[CustomAuthorize]
public class UserController : Controller
{
}
```

**Startup.cs**

```
public class Startup
{
    public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        Configuration = configuration;
    }

    public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddAuthentication(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme).AddCookie(o => o.LoginPath = new PathString("/Account/Login")); ;
        services.AddControllersWithViews().AddRazorRuntimeCompilation(); 
        services.AddOptions();
        services.Configure<DataConnection>(Configuration.GetSection("ConnectionStrings"));
        services.AddRepositoryDependency();
        services.AddServiceDependency();
        services.AddSingleton<IHttpContextAccessor, HttpContextAccessor>();
        
        services.AddMvc().AddNToastNotifyToastr(new ToastrOptions()
        {
            ProgressBar = false,
            PositionClass = ToastPositions.TopRight
        });
    }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }
        else
        {
            app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
            // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
            app.UseHsts();
        }
        app.UseNToastNotify();
        app.UseHttpsRedirection();
        app.UseStaticFiles();
        app.UseRouting();
        app.UseAuthentication();
        app.UseAuthorization();
        //app.UseMiddleware<CustomAuthorizeAttribute>();
        app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                name: "default",
                pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
        });
    }
}
```

Here I am implementing Custom Role based authorization so in authorize attirbute I want to fetch all the rights of the user and check whether user has right to access the action or not. In CustomAuthorize attribute I am not able to get connectionstring.

Tried this below code to get connectionstring but throwing error object does not contain defination for GetService.

```
var configuration = context.HttpContext.RequestServices.GetService(typeof(IConfiguration)); 

 var  connectionstring = configuration.GetService("Connectionstrings:DefaultConnection").Value;
```

Tried  like  injecting IConfiguration but  I  am  not able  place attribute  on Controller  because  it was expecting  to pass IConfiguration.

Any help will be appriciated . Thanks in  Advance.

Comment: You can resolve `IConfiguration` from `context.HttpContext.RequestServices`,  but you're making things harder for yourself by not following the recommended route. Create an authorization policy, a requirement, then a handler for it. You can inject DbContext or any dependency in the handler and allow/deny the request. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/policies?view=aspnetcore-5.0#use-a-handler-for-one-requirement

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**The first way**, you can use `context.HttpContext.RequestServices` to get the `IConfiguration`:

```
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection; //be sure add this reference...

public void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationFilterContext context)
{            
    try
    {
        if (context.HttpContext.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
        {
            var requiredRights = String.Format("{0}-{1}", context.HttpContext.Request.RouteValues["controller"].ToString(), context.HttpContext.Request.RouteValues["action"].ToString());
            var userName = context.HttpContext.User.Identity.Name;
            if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(userName))
            {
                var config = context.HttpContext.RequestServices.GetService<IConfiguration>();
                string connectionString = config.GetSection("ConnectionStrings:DefaultConnection").Value;
                //....
            }
        }
        else
        {
            context.Result = new RedirectResult("~/account/login");
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
    }
}
```

---

**The second way**, you can inject `IConfiguration` by constructor like below:

```
public class CustomAuthorizeAttribute : Attribute, IAuthorizationFilter
{
    private readonly string connectionString;

    public CustomAuthorizeAttribute(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        this.connectionString = configuration
                   .GetSection("ConnectionStrings:DefaultConnection").Value;
    }
    public void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationFilterContext context)
    {          
        try
        {
            if (context.HttpContext.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
            {
                var requiredRights = String.Format("{0}-{1}", context.HttpContext.Request.RouteValues["controller"].ToString(), context.HttpContext.Request.RouteValues["action"].ToString());
                var userName = context.HttpContext.User.Identity.Name;
                if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(userName))
                {
                    //....
                }
            }
            else
            {
                context.Result = new RedirectResult("~/account/login");
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
        }
    }
}
```

Controller:

```
[ServiceFilter(typeof(CustomAuthorizeAttribute))]
public class UserController : Controller
{
}
```

Register the service:

```
services.AddScoped<CustomAuthorizeAttribute>();
```

Comment: I have used your first way of approach but showing error object does not contain defination for GetSection. I already added namespace using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;

Comment: Please share your code to us.

Comment: Updated my code please check added by Startup.cs also

Comment: Is this a right way to implement IAuthorize  Filter. If I am implementing in wrong way then please help me with right approach. I dont know why I got -1 for my question. Thanks  alot for your help it worked with second way of approach but I want to do with first way of approach.

Comment: Are you sure you use the correct code as mine? I saw you use `configuration.GetService` instead of `GetSection`, also you said `but throwing error object does not contain defination for GetService.`. Please check you code carefully, be sure add `Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;` and `Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection; `. If my answer help you, could you please accept as an answer? Thanks.

Comment: Sorry Its my bad pasted the wrong code I updated that in my question. I already added Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration; and Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection; but still not working throwing the same error I dont know why.

Comment: Hi, please read my code carefully again. You also edit a wrong code. Please check if your code is: `var config = context.HttpContext.RequestServices.GetService<IConfiguration>();
                string connectionString = config.GetSection("ConnectionStrings:DefaultConnection").Value;`.  Just copy my answer. It is impossible to make error if you actually add the correct code and reference.